# magnific-popup inline gallery with multiple start points

Tags: javascript, gallery, inline, image-gallery, magnific-popup

Looking at this: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#inline-type

Working with this example: https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/sHoxp

Looking to display 3 images with each image opening at the right point in the gallery's rotation. So if the user clicks image 1st then the inline gallery will display the first image with accompanying data (preferably on the right-hand side like instagram.com's gallery), if users clicks the 3rd image then the inline gallery shows image 3 with its accompanying data and will rotate accordingly.

Right now it just loads the first image and data every time, obviously because there is only 1 button. But like I said trying to have 3 images with an inline gallery displaying at the right point. Any help apprecaited. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<button style="padding:20px;">Open popup</button>
```

CSS:

```
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
// Define data for the popup
var data = [
  {
    username: "Brad Frost", // Key "username" means that Magnific Popup will look for an element with class "mfp-username" in markup and will replace its inner HTML with the value.
    userWebsite_href: 'http://www.bradfrostweb.com', // Key "userWebsite_href" means that Magnific Popup will look for an element with class "mfp-userWebsite" and will change its "href" attribute. Instead of ending "href" you may put any other attribute.
    userAvatarUrl_img: 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1561258552/brad_frost_bigger.png', // Prefix "_img" is special. With it Magnific Popup finds an  element "userAvatarUrl" and replaces it completely with image tag.
    userLocation: 'Pittsburgh, PA'
  },

  {
    username: "Paul Irish",
    userWebsite_href: 'http://paulirish.com',
    userAvatarUrl_img: 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2910976341/7d972c32f3882f715ff84a67685e6acf_bigger.jpeg',
    userLocation: 'San Francisco'

  },

  {
    username: "Chris Coyier",
    userWebsite_href: 'https://css-tricks.com',
    userAvatarUrl_img: 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1668225011/Gravatar2_bigger.png',
    userLocation: 'Palo Alto, California'
  }
];

// initalize popup
$('button').magnificPopup({ 
  key: 'my-popup', 
  items: data,
  type: 'inline',
  inline: {
    // Define markup. Class names should match key names.
    markup: '<div class="white-popup"><div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
              '<a class="mfp-userWebsite">'+
                '<div class="mfp-userAvatarUrl"></div>'+
                '<h2 class="mfp-username"></h2>'+
              '</a>'+
              '<div class="mfp-userLocation"></div>'+
            '</div>'
  },
  gallery: {
    enabled: true 
  },
  callbacks: {
    markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
      // optionally apply your own logic - modify "template" element based on data in "values"
      // console.log('Parsing:', template, values, item);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/MmVEzQ ?

Comment: @Janis you legend! this looks awesome. thanks for sharing and making my day better :)